# Nested query with wildcard

Tags: mongodb-query

Imagine the following example.

```
{
 "a": {
  "id": 1,
  "b": {
   "items: {
    "1": {
     fieldA: "value",
     fieldB: "value"
    },
    "2": {
     fieldA: "value",
     fieldB: "value" 
    },
    "3": {
     fieldA: "value",
     fieldB: "value"
    },
   }
  }
 }
 "a": {
  "id": 2,
  "b": {
   "items: {
    "1": {
     fieldA: "value",
     fieldB: "value"
    },
    "2": {
     fieldA: "value"
    },
    "3": {
     fieldA: "value"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Now i want to get all a's where "fieldB" is missing inside any item. In the example above the result should be the the a with id==2. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution.

```
{
 { $project: { items: { $objectToArray: '$a.b.items' } } },
 { $match: { 'items.v.fieldB': { $exists : false } } }
}
```